# Wine программы для открытия файлов этого типа не сконфигурировано

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine

Скачал bottles и wine на линукс mint. При попытке запустить установщик фотошопа вылезает эта надпись "программы для открытия файлов этого типа не сконфигурировано". До этого попробовал запустить какие-то проги на playonlinx, но вылезала та же ошибка. Гуглил, но конкретного ответа не нашел. Помогите.

Comment: Даже если Вам кто то захочет помочь это будет сделать затруднительно. Таких ошибок быть не должно, если вы просто запускаете установщик для файла exe, а это скорее всего так. Какая версия WineHQ, какая разрядность prefix. Текущая версия стабилная WineHQ 8.0.2, Какую версию Windows вы выбрали в winecfg?